# Failing to Dual boot Ubuntu on Lenovo G50 Core i7 Windows 8.1 system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

Not able to install Ubuntu on Lenovo G50 Core i7  Windows 8.1 system. All the time the GRUB installer fails to install and the system directly boots to Windows 8.1.

Even when trying with the Ubuntu 15.04 version same thing happening.

Earlier with the older versions of windows I myself have installed them without much trouble but now UEFI and SECURE Boot is not helping much I guess?

The process I am trying to follow is shrinking my D drive in windows. So an unallocated space is created.

I am inserting the bootable USB selecting the BIOS option of booting through the USB.

And then following the instruction as given normally during the process. Only during the partition I select the Largest free continuous partition to install the Ubuntu system. I am not doing the Manual thing as I am not very much familiar with the process.

But at the end the GRUB is failing to install, all the time.

Comment: You can follow the steps [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/178596) to disable SecureBoot and UEFI, which may mean it will install more successfully.

Comment: Without that is it not possible to install? Please kindly tell?Throw some more light.

Comment: Although according to (this)[https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI] (read the full thing) if 8.1 was effectively installed in UEFI mode then Ubuntu has to be as well :/

Comment: Yes that's what is causing confusion.

Comment: How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. And if you install in BIOS mode, you have to go back into UEFI and change boot to BIOS. You cannot easily dual boot with Windows in UEFI but can dual boot. Install Ubuntu in UEFI. Do you have good backups. Older verisons will say they install over an existing Ubuntu but then erase entire hard drive if you use any of the auto install options on a re-install. Then you must use Something Else and chose same / (root) partition. http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Comment: Not clear @oldfred. So you mean to say that I should be trying to install the Ubuntu in the same setting under which Windows was installed.But I am doing the same thing and the Ubuntu option itself is not coming during boot time. Its directly booting to Windows.

Comment: When you installed was it in UEFI mode? UEFI has boot options and many allow you to set boot order in UEFI boot tab. Can you move ubuntu entry to first? It may still have Windows as first option. Some system also require work arounds. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I am inserting the bootable USB selecting the BIOS option of booting through the USB.

This is your problem. You're creating a disk on which Windows is (almost certainly) installed in EFI/UEFI mode and Ubuntu is installed in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. This makes for a *much* more complex boot process than if both OSes are installed in the same mode. At best, it means you must use the built-in boot manager or rEFInd to select which OS to boot, and at worst it becomes *impossible* to switch OSes. Given that you also report that GRUB didn't install, the latter is the case for you.

You can probably fix your problem by *disabling BIOS/CSM/legacy support* in the firmware and either running [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) or installing my [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and the appropriate EFI filesystem driver. Alternatively, after you disable BIOS/CSM/legacy support, you can re-install Ubuntu.